# Erro ao conectar Delphi 10.2 + Zeos + PostgreSql

Tags: delphi, zeos

Estou tentando conectar o Zeos em um banco de dados PostgreSql.

Já copiei todas as DLL para a pasta da aplicação.

O Zeos acha as DLL, mas dá um erro de incompatibilidade:

> Client-Library libpq.dll found but could not be loaded. Check compile-target and library compatibility!

Já copiei as DLL para a pasta windows e windows/system32 porém creio que o erro seja outro.

Minhas configurações:

Windows 10 64bit - PostgreSql 9 - Zeos 7.2.1 rc

**EDITADO**

Baixei as duas versões do PostgreSql (32bit e 64bit) e coloquei as dll em duas pastas. Quando o aplicativo abre, o cliente tem duas opções de conexão (32 ou 64). Consegui conectar no meu pc usando o 32bit, porém quando testei em outro pc (com as mesmas configurações), não deu certo.

Já registrei a DLL `libpq.dll`, mesmo assim, o erro persiste na outra máquina (Na minha conectou).

Comment: Tenta copiar para *Windows/SYSWOW64* porque seu Windows é 64 bits.

Comment: Além de Copiar, é importante registrar a DLL `regsvr32`..., lembrando de apontar o caminho do regsvr32 para o caminho adequado do sistema, 32/64

Comment: Pelas pesquisas que fiz, o erro se deve à DLL ser de 32bit e o SO de 64bit ou vice-versa. Consegui resolver no meu pc, mas quando fui pra outro pc, deu o mesmo erro... @JúniorMoreira sabe dizer se o Delphi faz esse registro?

Comment: No caso a instalação do Zeos deve ter feito, então você deve realizar o registro: `regsvr32 caminho\nome_dll`

Comment: Você quer dizer pra instalar o zeos no cliente?

Comment: Não, registrar a DLL que esta faltando.

Comment: não funcionou, mesmo registrando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é incluir a pasta onde estão as DLL, no PATH do Windows.

Meu Computador > Propriedades > Configurações Avançadas do Sistema > Variáveis de Ambiente

Nesse local, acrescentar o diretório das DLL na variável PATH.

Testei em diversos computadores e apenas uns poucos não funcionaram.